# Show different value if cell is different from the one above in Excel

Tags: excel

The issue Im dealing with is that I want Excel to recognize in a range when the next cell is different from the one above and display a different value.

For example, the first four rows are the same (Apple) so the values are increasing. However, A6 (Orange) is different than A5, so I want the values to start again showing (1:1).

Value I've got  -Value I want
Apple   - (1:1)
Apple   - (2:2)
Apple   - (3:3)
Apple   - (4:4)
Orange  - (1:1)
Pear    - (1:1)
Pear    - (2:2)
Pear    - (3:3)
Grapefruit  - (1:1)
Banana  - (1:1)
Banana  - (2:2)

Hopefully you can help me out!

Answer (score 0):

Anna you can use the below code assuming that the fruits are in column A and the required code will be in column B.

```
=IF(IFERROR(LEFT(A2,FIND("-",A2,1)-2),A2)=IFERROR(LEFT(B1,FIND("-",B1,1)-2),B1),IFERROR(LEFT(A2,FIND("-",A2,1)-2),A2)&" - ("&IFERROR(MID(B1,(FIND("(",B1,1)+1),1),0)+1&":"&IFERROR(MID(B1,(FIND("(",B1,1)+1),1),0)+1&")",IFERROR(LEFT(A2,FIND("-",A2,1)-2),A2)&" - (0:0)")
```

Also make sure to begin in column 2 not 1 (your data must has header).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to let it begin with (1:1) not (0:0) then use the below code:

```
=IF(IFERROR(LEFT(A2,FIND("-",A2,1)-2),A2)=IFERROR(LEFT(B1,FIND("-",B1,1)-2),B1),IFERROR(LEFT(A2,FIND("-",A2,1)-2),A2)&" - ("&IFERROR(MID(B1,(FIND("(",B1,1)+1),1),0)+1&":"&IFERROR(MID(B1,(FIND("(",B1,1)+1),1),0)+1&")",IFERROR(LEFT(A2,FIND("-",A2,1)-2),A2)&" - (1:1)")
```